# Issue with hide() and show() jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Can anybody help me with this issue?
I'd like to hide inputs that don't have any text in it. But nthing happens. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
Teste1: <input type="text" value="conteudo1" id="btn1" >
Teste2: <input type="text" id="btn2" >
Teste3: <input type="text" id="btn3" >
Teste4: <input type="text" value="conteudo4" id="btn4" >
Teste5: <input type="text" value="conteudo5" id="btn5" >
Teste6: <input type="text" id="btn6" >


</body>
</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    teste();

});

function teste(){
    for (i = 1  ; i < 7 ; i++) {
        if(('#btn'+i).val == 0){
            $('#btn'+i).show();
            else{
                $('#btn'+i).hide();
            }
        }

    }
}


</script>
```

Comment: change `('#btn'+i).val == 0` to `('#btn'+i).val().length == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code

- `('#btn'+i)` returns a string, which does not have `val` property so the condition will never be true, you need to use `$('#btn'+i).val()`
- I assume you want to hide both the label and the text, in that case you need to wrap them in an element

---

You can add a common class to all the elements to make it easier to select them.

Then you need to wrap the label and input in another element so that both can be hidden

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  teste();

});

function teste() {
  $('input.btn').filter(function() {
    return !!this.value;
  }).parent().hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Teste1: <input type="text" class="btn" value="conteudo1" id="btn1"></span>
<span>Teste2: <input type="text" class="btn" id="btn2"></span>
<span>Teste3: <input type="text" class="btn" id="btn3"></span>
<span>Teste4: <input type="text" class="btn" value="conteudo4" id="btn4"></span>
<span>Teste5: <input type="text" class="btn" value="conteudo5" id="btn5"></span>
<span>Teste6: <input type="text" class="btn" id="btn6"></span>
```

Comment: Oh my god, what a lack of attention!! Thanks man. Everything runs fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You make some error in your code. your else{} is in your if{}. Besides, in if statement, $ is missing for calling the element.

```
function teste(){
    for (i = 1  ; i < 7 ; i++) {
        if($('#btn'+i).val == 0){
            $('#btn'+i).show();
        }else{
            $('#btn'+i).hide();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what does this give you `$('#btn'+i).val` ? i dont get the upvote

Comment: The goal is is i there is an input already filled, hide this input.

I want to check if the input has any value with this line, but i forgot the () in .val